# SQL Server Management Studio 2012 - horrible blue background

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I've just installed SSMS 2012 and when I loaded it up I was presented with a nasty blue background - it looks so bad that I honestly thought something was broken, but apparently it's **supposed** to look like that!

Short of sending the SQL Server Design Team a set of vouchers to have their eyesight tested, is there anything that I can do to change this?  I've looked around and found a couple of other people whose sight has been similarly assaulted, but I cannot find a solution.

Comment: I haven't got SSMS 2012 on my machine here but I do at home and can't recall noticing this. Can you post a screenshot of the offending item?

Comment: @MartinSmith: They may be referring to the blue colour of SSMS 2012's empty workspace. @ paulH: Could you post a picture of what you are talking about, just to clear any doubts?

Comment: @AndriyM - Do you mean if you have no query windows open? Pretty much the first thing I do on opening SSMS is hit new query so maybe that's why I never noticed it.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Yes that one, and the overall theme is blueish as well: menus, panels, status bar etc. (I have no problem with it, just clarifying.)

Comment: Yes it's the empty workspace that I'm talking about. For some reason it puts me in mind of a screen that hasn't redrawn properly.  I can't quite work out why - it's not the colour itself, just the way it contrasts with the rest of the screen.

Comment: So what happens when you open a new query

Comment: Well it's based on Visual Studio so have you [had a look at this?](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378/)

Comment: If you're looking to change the default color scheme, you can also look at [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized). It doesn't address the empty workspace color issue but can make for more efficient color schemas

Comment: I agree, it does look odd.  When I first saw it I thought there was a loose VGA cable somewhere...definitely too much blue, especially the menu items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about the below appearance?

[image]

If that's the case, then I don't think that blue background is able to be changed.  I'm not sure why that'd be such a hang-up, as if you're staring at that background in SSMS, then you're probably not really doing anything.  Like Martin said above, the query window or other placeholders in that area will cover that completely.

When you have a query window open, it should look similar to the below screenshot:

[image]

As you can notice, you don't really see that blue background at all.  99% of the time (at least for me when I'm in SSMS), this will be the visual representation of SSMS.

Comment: I guess you're right and I should probably start doing some work :-)    It was just my initial reaction to it was "urgh!" and I decided that I had to change it.

Comment: @paulH Ha!!  Understandable, and your actual work progress was never in question. :-)